# Flutter - location permissions not being asked when using future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin to get user location in background.

The build of app is dependent on a future value where it first checks in initState if user is registered using a REST API, and poll location if user is registered or show Register button.

Below is relevant structure my code:

```js
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Location location = Location();

  Future<bool>? _registered;
  late bool _serviceEnabled;
  late PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
  late LocationData _locationData;

  Future<bool> fetchUserInfo() async {
    // checks if user is registered
  }

  Future<LocationData?> setLocationPermissions() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    await location.changeSettings(interval: 30000);
    await location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);

    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    return _locationData;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setLocationPermissions().then((value) {
      _locationData = value!;
    }); //this is supposed to ask for location permissions

    // Fetch user details from server
    _registered = fetchUserInfo();

    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      // do more stuff
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Manager'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _registered,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return _buildWidget(screenSize); // widget function that returns either a 
                                             // Register button or Text "You are registered"
                                             // based on another value set in fetchUserInfo
          } else if (snapshot.hasError){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: snapshot.error.toString());
            return const SizedBox();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I open the app on release apk, if a user is not registered it simply renders the register button from `_buildWidget`. My expectation is that it should ask for location permission based on code in `initState`. However it doesn't. It was working fine if I don't use a FutureBuilder ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310005/flutter-how-to-wait-for-async-call-to-finish-in-initstate))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem is that widget build up is somehow over-riding the locations popup or its future never makes it to user interface due to some error in setpermissions initialization or some conflict with widget tree..

I fixed it by putting all the code inside `initState` in one common async function and setting the `future` of the future builder to this common function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting location permission because inside your initState you have called some asynchronous events. Flutter lifecycle tells us that although initState runs first, but any asynchronous event takes time to run. That's why even though your function in initState called first but as they are asynchronous, the widget build method is triggering first and thus it overrides your location permission pop up.

To solve this, you can wrap another futureBuilder to your current futureBuilder. The first futureBuilder should have the location permission task and the second futureBuilder should have the _registered task.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it worked fine for me. Take a look :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => {
            [
              Permission.location,
              Permission.storage,
              Permission.bluetooth,
              Permission.bluetoothConnect,
              Permission.bluetoothScan
            ].request().then((status) {
              runApp(const MyApp());
            })
          });
}`
```